# Why is global object array suddenly null when it enters a method?

Tags: java, arrays

Why would a non-null global array suddenly become null in a method?

I have tried to move the method into the object class and access it that way since the getWeight() method works fine, but I have the same issue. As soon as I step into the viablePaths method the global arrays are null. I am using eclipse to toggle breakpoints and I can see everything in the arrays before I step into the method.

I would like the method to be able to access the paths and archs arrays and return an integer value. With the content of the arrays right now the method should set the pathIndex integer variable to -1. I do not know what else to put for the desired behavior. The desired behavior should be for the the global object arrays to not become null when the method is called.

Currently the error I get is a NullPointerException from the line where the determineViable paths method is called.

```
public class StackHelpProblem {
    public static int numEdges;
    public static int queries;
    public static Edge[] paths;
    public static Edge[] archs;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        numEdges = 3;
        queries = 2;
        
        Edge[] paths = new Edge[numEdges];
        paths[0] = new Edge(1);
        paths[1] = new Edge(2);
        paths[2] = new Edge(3);
        
        Edge[] archs = new Edge[queries];
        archs[0] = new Edge(10);
        archs[1] = new Edge(10);
        
        int pathIndex = 0;

        // Reachable artifacts set
        for (int i = 0; i < queries; i++) {
            System.out.println(archs[i].getWeight());
            pathIndex = determineViablePaths(archs[i].getWeight());
                
        }
    }
    
    // Method to return last index of path that can be traversed
    public static int determineViablePaths(int weight) {
                    
        for (int i = 0; i < numEdges; i++) {
            if (paths[i].getWeight() <= weight)
                continue;
            else {
                return i - 1;
                }
            }
        return numEdges-1;
    }
        
        // The edge class
        public static class Edge implements Comparable<Edge> {
        
        int weight;
            
        Edge(int weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
                }
            
        public int getWeight() {
            return this.weight;
            }
            
        // The Edge comparison method
        public int compareTo(Edge other) {
            if(this.weight < other.weight)
                return 0;
            else if (this.weight == other.weight)
                return 1;
            return -1 ;
            }
        }
}
```

the getWeight() works and the determineViablePath(int weight) method does not work. As soon as that method is entered the global arrays become null.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: "*Why would a non null global array suddenly appear null to a method?*" - I am willing to bet a significant amount of money that this is not what is happening. Please provide a [MRE].

Comment: Are you sure the `archs[i]` is `null`. Most likely you have `archs[i].getQueryIndex()` return an `Integer` and the cast to an `int` fails because the method returns `null`.

Comment: Declare your variables as final. You should get compilation error telling you when the field is set.

Comment: Have you initialized your arrays? They are null

Comment: @SilviuBurcea as mentioned in the question, they are (and must be) initialized, since the call to `getWeight()` works. I'm mostly 100% certain that the issue is the cast to `int` and this question is a mix-up in understanding `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will need to code something up in a bit, there is a lot of input not needed for the method in the object so let me trim it down and still reproduce the problem, and I will update. I don't want to post the whole thing.

Comment: Also, don't underestimate [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) :)

Comment: The arrays are initialized before the objects are added to them. I am using eclipse to step through and I can see everything that is supposed to be in the arrays before I step into the method, but as soon as I step into the method both arrays appear as null.

Comment: @George, what does it mean to declare the variables as final?

Comment: `public static final Event[] paths;` This means once set, `paths` cannot be changed.

Comment: @Philipp, I am not evening getting to the line with getQueryIndex.

Comment: @Scratte haha, thanks, my husband is my rubber duck.

Comment: @Knonymous123 In that case, your access within `determineViablePaths` to the arrays is incorrect. You state that `archs[i].getWeight()` returns a valid value so the array is initialized and available. Your code is for sure incomplete (where is for example `numPaths` coming from and where do you initialize the arrays). Please post a full code example.

Comment: @George Will doing that cause a problem with sorting the array? After I take input I sort the array by one of the members of the object.

Comment: It will be a problem if you're doing an `out of place` sort.

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` is an in place sort, so if you're using that it's fine.

Comment: It says I am not providing enough debugging details now, but I tried to turn it into a minimal reproducible example, like @Turing85 suggested.

Comment: @Knonymous123 in method `main`, two new arrays `paths` and `archs` are created. Those are **not** the static variables `paths` and `archs`. If we change `Edge[] paths = new Edge[numEdges];` and `Edge[] archs = new Edge[queries];` to `paths = new Edge[numEdges];` and `archs = new Edge[queries];`, [the exception will not occur](https://ideone.com/HlURE0).

Comment: @Turing85 thank you so so much. This was admittedly kind of a stressful experience so I am really happy you were able to spot my super noob mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us analyze the relevant parts of the code to understand why the `Exception` is thrown and how we can prevent it.

```
public class StackHelpProblem {
    ...
    public static Edge[] paths;
    public static Edge[] archs;
    ...
}
```

The two static fields `Edge[] paths` and `Edge[] archs` are not initialized and thus implicitly initialized with `null`.

```
public class StackHelpProblem {
    ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        Edge[] paths = new Edge[numEdges];
        ...
        Edge[] archs = new Edge[queries];
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In method `static void main(...)`, two **new** arrays `paths` and `archs` are created. Those do **not** reference the static fields. Thus, the static fields are still initialized with `null`.

In method `static int determineViablePaths(...)`, no local variable `paths` is found, thus static field `paths` is used, which still is `null`. Thus, the array-access will result in a `NullPointerException`.

We can get rid of the `NullPointerException` by using the existing static fields instead of creating new variables in method `static void main(...)`:

```
public class StackHelpProblem {
    ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        paths = new Edge[numEdges];
        ...
        archs = new Edge[queries];
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/HlURE0)